# sorting a file by index position in python

Tags: python, sorting, reorderlist

If I wanted to sort a list by student number (small sample below but the list would be larger than this):

- Stephen, 97654, DOB: Mar 5, 1985
- Kelly, 58374, DOB: Dec 18, 1986
- Brian, 12587, DOB: May 20, 1985

  `f = open('studentdb.txt')
      for line in f:
      g = line.split(',')
      print(g)`

Which gives me:

`['Stephen', ' 97654', ' DOB: Mar 5', ' 1985\n']
['Kelly', ' 58374', ' DOB: Dec 18', ' 1986\n']
['Brian', ' 12587', ' DOB: May 20', ' 1985\n']`

How would I go about sorting the file and reordering it by student number?

Comment: Can you read the entire file into memory?

Answer (score 3):

Use csv to read it and then sort on the second field:

```
import csv

with open(fn) as f:
    lines=[line for line in csv.reader(f)]
    print lines   # unsorted
    print sorted(lines, key=lambda line: int(line[1]))
```

First prints the file:

```
[['Stephen', ' 97654', ' DOB: Mar 5', ' 1985'], 
 ['Kelly', ' 58374', ' DOB: Dec 18', ' 1986'], 
 ['Brian', ' 12587', ' DOB: May 20', ' 1985']]
```

Then the sorted version:

```
[['Brian', ' 12587', ' DOB: May 20', ' 1985'], 
 ['Kelly', ' 58374', ' DOB: Dec 18', ' 1986'], 
 ['Stephen', ' 97654', ' DOB: Mar 5', ' 1985']]
```

Once you have the sorted version, reopen the file for writing and write out the file using csv again.

Answer (score 0):

You can save a list of list like this:

```
f = open('studentdb.txt')
for line in f:
    g = line.split(',')
    StudentList.append(g)
```

Then sort by the second element with:

```
StudentList.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[1]))
```